# Помогите избавиться от повтора prompt в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.

Сделал вот такую страничку. Когда я очищаю поле или ввожу неверное значение его размера - выскакивает окно prompt. Так и должно быть. Но когда я делаю это второй и последующие разы - окно выскакивает уже не один раз, а в количестве по геометрической прогрессии: 2, 4, 8 раз и т.д. Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить этот недочёт в JS.

Заранее благодарю.

```js
$(document).ready(function squareSize() {
  var side = +prompt("Select size of square area: 16, 32 or 64");

  switch (side) {
    case 16:
      for (var i = 1; i <= Math.pow(side, 2); i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="square big"></div>');
      }
      break;
    case 32:
      for (var i = 1; i <= Math.pow(side, 2); i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="square medium"></div>');
      }
      break;
    case 64:
      for (var i = 1; i <= Math.pow(side, 2); i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="square small"></div>');
      }
      break;
    default:
      alert('Wrong value! Try again.');
      squareSize();
  }

  $('.square').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('painted')
  });

  $('.square').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('painted')
  });

  $('#erase').on('mouseup', function() {
    $('.square').remove();
    squareSize();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eaeae8;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #4c0017;
}

#container {
  height: 512px;
  width: 512px;
  border: 5px solid #b40220;
  padding: 1px;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #e9e0cf;
}

.big {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}

.medium {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}

.small {
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
}

.painted {
  background-color: #4c0017;
}

#erase {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  color: #4c0017;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 1px 1px, rgba(100, 100, 100, .3) 3px 7px 3px;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px / 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .0) 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .8), rgba(255, 255, 255, .0) 70%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(125, 125, 125, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(125, 125, 125, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(125, 125, 125, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(125, 125, 125, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(223, 190, 170, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(223, 190, 170, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(223, 190, 170, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(223, 190, 170, .5));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200% 100%, auto, 100% 2px, 100% 2px, 100% 1px, 100% 1px;
  background-position: 200% 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 4px, 0 calc(100% - 4px);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 3px 10px 10px -10px;
}

#erase:hover {
  transition: .5s linear;
  background-position: -200% 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 4px, 0 calc(100% - 4px);
}

#erase:active {
  top: 1px;
}

#menu-size {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Move the mouse cursor over the square area</h1>
<center>
  <div id="container"></div>
</center>
<button id="erase">Erase</button>
```

Comment: Каждое событие **mouseup** вызывает вашу функцию, которая добавляет ещё один обработчик этого события. Первый раз у вас один обработчик, 2 раз 2, 3 раз 4.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Михаил. Как мне можно избавиться от этого?

Answer (score 2):

Cделайте `squareSize` отдельной функцией, которая не добавляет обработчики событий к элементам DOM-a. Кроме того, измените регистрацию событий на `mouseenter` и `click`, чтобы обработчики вызывались для элементов, созданных позднее.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function squareSize() {
    var side = +prompt("Select size of square area: 16, 32 or 64");

    switch (side) {
    case 16:
      for (var i = 1; i <= Math.pow(side, 2); i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="square big"></div>');
      }
      break;
    case 32:
      for (var i = 1; i <= Math.pow(side, 2); i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="square medium"></div>');
      }
      break;
    case 64:
      for (var i = 1; i <= Math.pow(side, 2); i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="square small"></div>');
      }
      break;
    default:
      alert('Wrong value! Try again.');
      squareSize();
    }
  }

  $('#container').on('mouseenter', '.square', function() {
    $(this).addClass('painted')
  });

  $('#container').on('click', '.square', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('painted')
  });

  $('#erase').on('mouseup', function() {
    $('.square').remove();
    squareSize();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отменить текущее выполнение функции и не навешивать события повторно, достаточно выйти из функции при рекурсивном вызове:

```
return squareSize();
```

Также, стоит сменить обработчик удаления на `one`, потому что он вызывает функцию снова.

```js
$(document).ready(function squareSize() {
  var side = +prompt("Select size of square area: 16, 32 or 64");

  switch (side) {
    case 16:
      for (var i = 1; i <= Math.pow(side, 2); i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="square big"></div>');
      }
      break;
    case 32:
      for (var i = 1; i <= Math.pow(side, 2); i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="square medium"></div>');
      }
      break;
    case 64:
      for (var i = 1; i <= Math.pow(side, 2); i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="square small"></div>');
      }
      break;
    default:
      alert('Wrong value! Try again.');
      return squareSize();
  }

  $('.square').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('painted')
  });

  $('.square').on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('painted')
  });

  $('#erase').one('mouseup', function() {
    $('.square').remove();
    squareSize();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eaeae8;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: #4c0017;
}

#container {
  height: 512px;
  width: 512px;
  border: 5px solid #b40220;
  padding: 1px;
}

.square {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #e9e0cf;
}

.big {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}

.medium {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}

.small {
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
}

.painted {
  background-color: #4c0017;
}

#erase {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  color: #4c0017;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 1px 1px, rgba(100, 100, 100, .3) 3px 7px 3px;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px / 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .0) 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .8), rgba(255, 255, 255, .0) 70%), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(125, 125, 125, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(125, 125, 125, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(125, 125, 125, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(125, 125, 125, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(223, 190, 170, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(223, 190, 170, .5)), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(223, 190, 170, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 45%, rgba(223, 190, 170, .5));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 200% 100%, auto, 100% 2px, 100% 2px, 100% 1px, 100% 1px;
  background-position: 200% 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 4px, 0 calc(100% - 4px);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 3px 10px 10px -10px;
}

#erase:hover {
  transition: .5s linear;
  background-position: -200% 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 4px, 0 calc(100% - 4px);
}

#erase:active {
  top: 1px;
}

#menu-size {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Move the mouse cursor over the square area</h1>
<center>
  <div id="container"></div>
</center>
<button id="erase">Erase</button>
```

- *Ответ @Igor более корректен*

Comment: @Igor большое спасибо. у меня была такая идея и я даже пробовал это закинуть в отдельную функцию, но у меня что-то не так вышло значит.